# Writing iron python method with ref or out parameter

Tags: c#, ironpython

i need to translate following C# method to the same IronPhyton method

```
private void GetTP(string name, out string ter, out int prov)
{
  ter = 2;
  prov = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python (and consequently in IronPython) you cannot change a parameter that is not mutable (like strings)

So you can't directly traslate the given code to python, but you must do something like:

```
def GetTP(name):
  return tuple([2, 1])
```

and when you call it you must do:

```
retTuple = GetTP(name)
ter = retTuple[0]
prov = retTuple[1]
```

that is the same behaviour when in IronPython you call a C# method containing out/ref parameters.

In fact, in that case IronPython returns a tuple of out/ref parameters, and if there's a return value is the first in the tuple.

EDIT:
actually it's possible to override a method with out/ref parameters, look here:

http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#methods-with-ref-or-out-parameters

Comment: i wanted to explain problem simple as possible, that is why i used that example method. 

Real problem is that this method overrides method in base class and i must provide same signature in IronPhyton to override base method.

I tried your way but i doesnt help...

Answer (score 2):

Python script something like this should work:

```
ter = clr.Reference[System.String]()
prov = clr.Reference[System.Int32]()

GetTP('theName', ter, prov)

print(ter.Value)
print(prov.Value)
```