# Python .NET: "Cannot instantiate enumeration"

Tags: c#, python, python.net

So I've managed to import a managed .NET assembly in Python .NET, and got as far as setting up several objects and calling a few functions, but I cannot figure out how this one is supposed to work.

This is the C# code that I am trying to port:

```
            // read event sticky clears all initial events
            CML_EVENT_STATUS status=0;
            xAxisAmp.ReadEventSticky(ref status);
            statusTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(status);
```

---

I can import the `CML_EVENT_STATUS`, which reports it is `<class 'CMLCOMLib.CML_EVENT_STATUS'>`, but when I try to create an instance of it, I get this error:

```
>>> stat = CML_EVENT_STATUS()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot instantiate enumeration
```

If there's another way to call the function I haven't been able to figure it out. I've tried calling `xAxisAmp.ReadEventSticky()` and `xAxisAmp.ReadEventSticky(0)`, which just return `TypeError: No method matches given arguments`.

The closest I got was this error from `xAxisAmp.ReadEventSticky(CML_EVENT_STATUS)`:

```
System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.RuntimeType' cannot be converted to type 'CMLCOMLib.CML_EVENT_STATUS&'.
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't find any documentation on declaring enum types or passing them by reference, and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Python added an `Enum` class in 3.4: http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html Is your enum based on this? If so, `status = CML_EVENT_STATUS(0)` should be equivalent to your first line.

Comment: Or e.g. if `0`'s name is `SOME_EVENT`, I'd expect you could simply write `CML_EVENT_STATUS.SOME_EVENT` to get that value.

Comment: This is in Python 2.7, and I tried that one too. Same `cannot instantiate enumeration` error. You can access the enum names like you said, but I still can't call the function at all.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. See C# code at http://pastebin.com/c3eAca14 and Python console log at http://pastebin.com/z1SEWbvT So `CML_EVENT_STATUS.SOME_EVENT` (with correct name) ought to work for you. Note how the `ref` parameter is handled, as a return value like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2857287/781792) (Python for .NET works the same as IronPython here)

Comment: Eureka! The trick was declaring `stat` as an enum member!
`stat = CML_EVENT_STATUS.EVENT_STATUS_BRAKE` then
`stat = amp.ReadEventSticky(stat)` worked perfectly! Thanks so much!

Comment: Cool, I'll turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to instantiate an enum like this in Python .NET is:

```
stat = CML_EVENT_STATUS.EVENT_STATUS_BRAKE
```

Then you can call the method like so:

```
stat = amp.ReadEventSticky(stat)
```

Note that `ref` and `out` parameters don't work the same way in Python as in C#. As described in more detail in [Writing iron python method with ref or out parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857287/writing-iron-python-method-with-ref-or-out-parameter), `ref` and `out` parameters are returned from a method instead of modifying the variables that were passed in. If there are multiple return values (e.g. the method returns a value and there is a `ref` parameter), then a tuple will be returned with the method's return value first, followed by the `ref` and `out` parameters in order.

Assuming `ReadEventSticky` is `void`, this is pretty simple: it just returns the new `CML_EVENT_STATUS` value.